# How can I stop a css background resizing to fit the browser window?

Tags: css, xhtml

When using a css background such as in the footer on the page below (in the elements `div.footer_head` and `div.footer_footer`), if the browser window is resized to less than about `1000px` the divs themselves remain at the full width but scrolling right in the browser causes whitespace to appear where the background should be.

I was sure I'd find a similar question on here but can't seem to word it correctly enough to find it in search.

If someone could point me in the right direction I'm sure I can figure this out.

Look at how the divs with class `footer_head` and `footer_footer` behave when you resize the browser to be quite thin and scroll to the right.

[screenshot http://printanomics.unbranded-nomads.co.uk/picture-2.jpg](http://printanomics.unbranded-nomads.co.uk/picture-2.jpg)

Comment: could you post an example and say what you want to change on it exactly?

Comment: done, will try get a screenshot

Comment: a jsFiddle link with some code will be fine to help us helping you :)

Comment: Don't think I can make a jsFiddle very easily as it's a magento site I'm working on... I just use the live css editor in google chrome. Is jsFiddle better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042979/100-width-bg-images-not-extending-on-horizontal-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `min-width:1000px` to `.footer-container`.

```
.footer-container {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px; /* add this */
}
```

This will mean the smallest `width` the `.footer-container` will get is `1000px`. Though after that it will expand to 100%.

Comment: Thank you! Not a perfect solution, this seemed to leave another 50px whitespace at the right, which is weird... I've made it min-width:1050px; and it goes the full width, but I'm worried that might make horizontal scrollbars appear on a 1024x768 screen.

I don't have time to make it support every resolution perfectly but a bit annoying considering everything else is 1000px or less...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at your css file you will see that the footer width is set to 100% and not 1000px as the other divs. This also applies to your background as your background won't be bigger than the div itself.

I don't know if you use this, but Firebug is a very good Firefox plugin to identify troubles in CSS files.

Comment: I use chrome which has something similar I think. I can't seem to figure out which divs would need fixed width and which would need a percentage though...

Comment: While coding it is always good to have different browsers because a same website might not look the same on different browsers…

I've just applied the min-width: 1000px to .footer-container class

Comment: Chrome does indeed have something similar. Right click on an element within the document and select "Inspect Eelement" or via the spanner menu visit "tools" >> "developer tools".

Comment: I'm aware, not used firebug very much though, chrome > firefox imo atm! I like firefox for debugging javascript better at times though, the errors go into more detail.